# Loop through the digits of a number, and do sums and subtracts in Java

Tags: java

How can I loop through the digits in a number, and do sum & subtract to every possible combination using Java?

for example let's take the number 114, I want to output it like this:

```
1+1+4 = 6
1+1-4 = -2
1-1+4 = 4
1-1-4 = -4
11+4  = 15
11-4  = 7
1+14  = 15
1-14  = 13
114   = 114
```

Comment: Are you looking for a recursive or an iterative algorithm?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm actually a newbie so whatever solves the problem is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well I know that, but if we solve it for you, nobody wins. I *assume* this is some assignment and you're expected to solve this with recursion.

Comment: Actually it was a programming challenge that took place last year, and it didn't specify. If you can do both, then I'll learn something new.

Comment: That's not exactly correct. I *can* do both (I swear), but programming is a lot about learning to think in a certain way. If you just look at the end results, you won't learn nearly as much as if you spend time solving it yourself. Especially since there is a lot of material on the internet for you to study.

Comment: Flagged as unclear since you didn't explain what your specific question is, but just asked for someone to write something for you.

Comment: You're right man, this is what I do usually, I've been searching and trying for hours, my problem is not with loop it's with the + and - are they hard coded is there a certain order .. Any hints maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use % operator to get each digit. Last digit from a number is the_number % 10. And to get the next digit you should do the_number = the_number / 10. After you get a digit you can put it into an array, count the digits in another variable (counter++) and after you have all digits you can sum them. For 114 your array will be [4,1,1] because you always get the last digit and if you want to do 11 + 4 you can take the last 1 (last element from array), multiply it by 10 and add 1 and 4. Same for 1-14, take the last 1 (last element from array) - ( 1 multiplied by 10 + 4).